# Store a value for "total number of time spent" in iPhone app

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsdate

I am developing an iPhone application which stores the total time spent at a certain activity. I let the user press a button to start the activity and then stop. How can I store a value that keeps adding the time spent on the activity overall in the form of hours, minutes and seconds? (in Core Data or otherwise). For example: it can be shown like

**Total time spent in a week: 08:12:05**
could mean that the user spent 8 hours, 12 minutes and 5 seconds on the particular activity.

NSDate is unable to do it. I looked at NSTimer but that is kind of the opposite of what I'm looking for. I'm not thorough with all the api for iOS but is there something I can work with?

Comment: What Scott mentioned seems to be the easiest way to do it. However, I came across this class, just wanted to share it. Don't know if it is really helpful though.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply store `NSDate`s for start and stop time, every time the user starts the activity. The time spent can be derived from these dates with `-timeIntervalSinceDate:`.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree with Scott. If it was me I'd create a separate entity to hold activity times, each with a start and end time and whatever other data I need for that activity.

If you really prefer to store an accumulated time value, just store the number of seconds as one of the numeric types. Converting between that and the number of hours, minutes, and seconds is simple.